# Create Model with HasMany relation using Repository Pattern

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to implement the repository pattern and save a relationship using the create method as shown below.

```
abstract class EloquentRepository implements Repository {
    public function create($data)
    {
        return $this->model->create($data);
    }
}
```

Within my controller I have injected the repository:

```
public function __construct(SubscriberRepository $subscriberRepository,
                                SubscribableRepository $subscribableRepository)
    {
        $this->subscriberRepository = $subscriberRepository;
        $this->subscribableRepository = $subscribableRepository;
    }
```

My store method looks like:

```
public function store(CreateSubscriberRequest $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $subscribable = $this->subscribableRepository->findByIdentifier($request->input('type'))
            ->firstOrFail();

                $attributes = [
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'email' => $request->input('email')
        ];

        $subscriber = $this->subscriberRepository->create($attributes);
    }
```

**Subscriber Model**

```
public function subscribable()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Subscribable::class, 'subscribable_id');
    }
```

***Subscribable Model***

```
public function subscribers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Subscriber::class);
    }
```

My issue **General error: 1364 Field 'subscribable_id' doesn't have a default value** is because the subscribable_id is a foreign key and not set in the create method.

How do I relate the subscribable model, setting the *subscribable_id*? I don't think setting the *subscribable_id* in the fillable property is the way to go with this.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel gives functionality to save relations using the related model instances.
So You can save relation by calling create method on relation like this:

```
public function store(CreateSubscriberRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $subscribable = $this->subscribableRepository->findByIdentifier($request->input('type'))
        ->firstOrFail();

    $attributes = [
        'name' => $request->input('name'),
        'email' => $request->input('email')
    ];

    $subscribable->subscribers()->create($attributes);
}
```

See [laravel doc on relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

Comment: Many thanks! Am I right in thinking it's not the responsibility of the repository to store the data?

Comment: The repository provides you an extra layer of abstraction and there is no harm to save data through repository